XML LINQ matching trouble
XML:
<DLC>
    <ObjectClass>RVM_GWR_Class166_DMSL_C</ObjectClass>
    <ShortName>Class166</ShortName>
</DLC>
<DLC>
    <ObjectClass>RVM_BR_Class170_DMCL_W_C</ObjectClass>
    <ShortName>Class170</ShortName>
</DLC>

Previous code:
var values = xml.Descendants("DLC")
    .Where(i => i.Element("ObjectClass").Value == locoName)
    .Select(DLC => new
    {
        ShortName = (string)DLC.Element("ShortName"),
        DisplayName = (string)DLC.Element("DisplayName"),
    });

Currently, the code works by checking whether the locoName string matches the ObjectClass XML element.
But what I really need to do is something like this:
.Where(locoName.Contains(i => i.Element("ShortName").Value))

The above does not compile due to:

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

I need to make a match where the locoName string contains the ShortName XML Element.
The locoName will be something like this: "RVM_GWR_Class166_Z_ABC123" ie; the Class166 part will match.
I can't quite work out how to do that in LINQ.

Your .Where expression is incorrect. It should be:
.Where(x => locoName.Contains(x.Element("ShortName").Value))

to check the locoName contains the ShortName property value.
var values = xml.Descendants("DLC")
    .Where(x => locoName.Contains(x.Element("ShortName").Value))
    .Select(DLC => new
    {
        ShortName = (string)DLC.Element("ShortName"),
        DisplayName = (string)DLC.Element("DisplayName"),
    });


Demo @ .NET Fiddle

Thanks, im still trying to figute out how to use the Lambda expressions.
